How Can LibreOffice Convert Milliseconds To Timestamp Or DateTime?
In LibreOffice I had converted timestamps into milliseconds because I didn't find a built-in way to naturally handle a standard time format. But now for real people, I want to convert that time easily back into rationally readable time.
Does LibreOffice have a way to auto-interpolate dates and 24-hour time like MS-Office Excel or Google-Suite Sheets?
// Example Times: 
Start Time: 00:00:00.000 
End Time: 00:01:00.000
Elapsed Time: 60000


Please [edit] and provide some before and after data and also specify milliseconds from what starting point.
